# Диалоги через WebSocket

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

Пытаюсь реализовать мгновенные сообщения через сокеты, проблема заключается в том, что любое написанное сообщение могут читать все.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу отправить сообщение только определенному пользователю?

```
var URL = 'ws://localhost:8181';
var chatClient = null;

function connect(){
    chatClient = new WebSocket(URL);

    chatClient.onmessage = function (event) {
        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(event.data);

        var messagesArea = $("#messageTable");
        var trTable = document.createElement('tr');

        var tdTable = document.createElement('td');
        tdTable.className = 'message-from';

        var aTable = document.createElement('a');
        aTable.className = 'angled-img';

        var adivTable = document.createElement('div');
        adivTable.className = 'img';
        adivTable.style = 'width:40px; margin-left:-10px;';
        adivTable.innerHTML = '<img src="'+jsonObj.userPic+'">';

        var spanTable = document.createElement('span');
        spanTable.className = 'message-from-name';
        //spanTable.style = 'margin-left:-60px;';
        spanTable.innerHtml = '<?=$accinfo['username'];?>';

        var spanDataTable = document.createElement('span');
        spanDataTable.className = 'date';
        //spanDataTable.style = 'margin-left:-60px;';
        spanDataTable.innerHTML = '<?=$date?>';  

        var tdDescriptTable = document.createElement('td');
        tdDescriptTable.className = 'message-description';

        var msgDescriptTable = document.createElement('div');
        msgDescriptTable.className = 'message-excerpt';
        msgDescriptTable.innerHTML = jsonObj.message;

        var tdActionTable = document.createElement('td');
        tdActionTable.className = 'message-action';

        var actTable = document.createElement('a');
        actTable.className = 'message-delete';

        var iTable = document.createElement('i');
        iTable.className = 'fa fa-times';

        trTable.appendChild(tdTable);

        tdTable.appendChild(aTable);
        aTable.appendChild(adivTable);

        tdTable.appendChild(spanTable);
        tdTable.appendChild(spanDataTable);

        tdTable.appendChild(tdDescriptTable);
        tdDescriptTable.appendChild(msgDescriptTable);

        trTable.appendChild(tdActionTable);
        tdActionTable.appendChild(actTable);
        actTable.appendChild(iTable);

        messagesArea.append(trTable);
        $(".comments-block").animate({scrollTop: $(".comments-block")[0].scrollHeight}, -500);  

    };
}
connect();

function sendMessage() {
    var convId = $("#conversation_id").val();
    var usrfromId = $("#user_from").val();
    var usrtoId = $("#user_to").val();
    var userPic = '<?=$usrPhoto?>';
    var inputElement = $("#mess").val();

    if (inputElement !== "") {
        var jsonObj = {"convId" : convId, "usrfromId" : usrfromId, "usrtoId" : usrtoId, "message" : inputElement, "userPic" : userPic};
        chatClient.send(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
    }
}

function disconnect () {
    chatClient.close();
}
```

C#

```
class Server
        {
            static readonly List<IWebSocketConnection> allSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
            static readonly WebSocketServer server = new WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:8181");

            static void Main()
            {
                FleckLog.Level = LogLevel.Debug;
                server.Start(socket =>
                {
                    socket.OnOpen = () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Open!");
                        allSockets.Add(socket);
                    };
                    socket.OnClose = () =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Close!");
                        allSockets.Remove(socket);
                    };
                    socket.OnMessage = message =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(message);
                        allSockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send(message));
                    };
                });


                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                while (input != "exit")
                {
                    foreach (var socket in allSockets.ToList())
                    {
                        socket.Send(input);
                    }
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                }

            }

            static void SendToSocketById(String input, Guid id)
            {
                var socket = allSockets.Find(client => client.ConnectionInfo.Id == id);
                socket.Send(input);
            }

        }
```

Comment: >>allSockets.ToList()<< вас не смущает это место?

Comment: У вас уже реализован полноценный метод SendToSocketById, в чём тогда ваш вопрос?

Comment: @test123 allSockets.ToList() в том то и дело, что я не представляю как с этим работать.. Если уберу этот код, то ничего не работает, с кодом ниже тоже ничего не смогла сделать (

Comment: о_О ну, вы же это писали... что значит не представляете? Вы пишите прямым текстом - "перебрать всех клиентов, и каждому отослать сообщение". Если хотите ответить конкретному клиенту - возьмите конкретно его сокет и шлите ему сообщение. Вот и вся задача.

Comment: @test123 мне нужно отправить сообщение по id пользователя, но не по Guid, даже не представляю, как сделать проверку

Comment: В момент когда вы добавляете входящее соединение на сервере, вы знаете что к вам зашёл какой то пользователь. Запросите его ник или id, когда он ответит, закрепите за соединением эту информацию. Соответственно, вы сможете идентифицировать все сокеты, и знать какие id за ними стоят.

Comment: Тоесть, после того как в js вы делаете chatClient = new WebSocket(URL); вам надо первым делом отправить серверу свой ник: chatClient.send(txtLogin.value()); как пример, где txtLogin - ссылка на текстовое поле с логином пользователя. Либо, придумать свои id.

Comment: В этот же момент, в серверной части на c#, в лямбде socket.OnOpen = () => необходимо перед добавление сокета в пулл считать его ник. Далее, хранить и сокеты и их ники, например, в своём классе-контейнере.

Comment: @test123 отправляю логин `chatClient.send('<?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>');`  не понимаю, где искать allSockets.Add(socket); -  тут нет такого (

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71848/discussion-between-test123-and-).